# Outputting a string into a JADE/PUG file

Tags: pug, template-engine, pugjs

So I have an issue where the string I'm reading in contains newlines, and I'm parsing the newlines in my JS file like so

```
var str = post.content.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br/>;');
```

For example, I want my text:

```
Hello World! How's it going?
```

to become

```
Hello World!

How's it going?
```

But instead, I'm getting

```
Hello World! <br/> How's it going?
```

How would I best approach this? It seems the logic I imported from HTML will not work in JADE/PUG

Comment: how are you outputting this text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are stuck with the variable interpolation issue. Please see the [pugjs documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) regarding the same.

For eg. when putting the `str` value to a tag, mark it as a safe string in pug template:

```
- var str = post.content.replace(/[\r\n]/g, '<br/>;');
p !{str}
//- or
p= str
```